# How to import data from cvs which some field contains " " by using load data infie

Tags: sql

I have some columns want to insert a existing table, some columns have contents like this"how, using,list, file",each column is separated by",",so how do I use load data infile to import them?

Comment: That highly depends if you use mysql, mssql, oracle, sybase, db2, pgsql so which one is it? And didn't you get that same warning when you added the sql tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't indicate which db you're using, So I'll answer you for mysql.
Please see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

> If the lines in such a file are terminated by carriage return/newline pairs, the statement shown here illustrates the field- and line-handling options you would use to load the file:
>
> `LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
>    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
>    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
>    IGNORE 1 LINES;`

And further down the page:

> Occurrences of the ENCLOSED BY character within a field value are escaped by prefixing them with the ESCAPED BY character. Also note that if you specify an empty ESCAPED BY value, it is possible to inadvertently generate output that cannot be read properly by LOAD DATA INFILE. For example, the preceding output just shown would appear as follows if the escape character is empty. Observe that the second field in the fourth line contains a comma following the quote, which (erroneously) appears to terminate the field:
>
> `1,"a string",100.20
>   2,"a string containing a , comma",102.20
>   3,"a string containing a " quote",102.20
>   4,"a string containing a ", quote and comma",102.20`

So, if you have unescaped `""` inside columns these data could not be imported in the general case, and you'll have either to export data using correct `ENCLOSED BY` character, or preprocess the file to escape `"` first.

If you just have `,` inside your columns, then it's easy, you'll have to use `ENCLOSED BY` and `TERMINATED BY`.